# rails / stimulus / underscored controller name, problems to name via ruby data attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

Given the controller `awesome_app_controller.js`, registered as `awseome_app`

```
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['input'];
}
```

The following :

```
<%= content_tag(:div, nil, data: { "awesome_app-target" => "input" }) %>
```

Will invariably ends up being named

```
<div data-awesome-app-target='input'></div>
```

and wont be detected by the stimulus controller as a target.

Assuming I dont want / can't rename this controller, is there a way to keep using ruby data attributes, and still get this use case through ?

Comment: How do you register this controller?

Comment: @mechnicov with underscores (https://gist.github.com/benbonnet/9354fedbf6aa106d3e8a71db69381132), i was unaware that by convention rails was dash'ing it. Thanks a lot for you clear answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like valid data attribute for [targets](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/targets):

```rb
data-awesome-app-target="input"
```

Here `awesome-app` is controller [identifier](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#identifiers)

Ease of Stimulus usage is ensured by compliance with [the convention](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#naming-conventions): when an identifier is composed of more than one word, write the words in kebab-case (i.e., by using dashes). In filenames, separate multiple words using either underscores or dashes (snake_case or kebab-case: `controllers/date_picker_controller.js`, `controllers/list-item-controller.js`)

An identifier is the name you use to reference a controller class in HTML

The following is an example of how Stimulus will generate identifiers for controllers in its require context:

| If your controller file is named… | its identifier will be… |
| --- | --- |
| clipboard_controller.js | clipboard |
| date_picker_controller.js. | date-picker |
| users/list_item_controller.js. | users--list-item |
| local-time-controller.js. | local-time |

Therefore by convention your controller from `awesome_app_controller.js` should be registered as `awesome-app`. You can register it [manually](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#registering-controllers-manually). First import the class, then call the `Application#register` method on your application object:

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/index.js
import AwesomeAppController from './awesome_app_controller'
application.register('awesome-app', AwesomeAppController)
```